# Why Twitter API returning JSON starting "delete"

Tags: api, twitter

## Question

Twitter API returns the message with "delete". Please help understand what this means and why the API is returning this message.

```
{  
   "delete":{  
      "status":{  
         "id":406461955981840384,
         "id_str":"406461955981840384",
         "user_id":****,
         "user_id_str":"****"
      },
      "timestamp_ms":"1562915550977"
   }
}
```

Before getting this message, I have got 420 (due to limited rate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a status deletion notice from the standard streaming API. According to the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/streaming-message-types):

> Status deletion notices (delete)
>
> These messages indicate that a given Tweet has been deleted. Client code must honor these messages by clearing the referenced Tweet from memory and any storage or archive, even in the rare case where a deletion message arrives earlier in the stream that the Tweet it references.

```
{
"delete":{
"status":{
"id":1234,
"id_str":"1234",
"user_id":3,
"user_id_str":"3"
}
}
}
```

Comment: can you also comment on the V2 delete status , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235467/tweet-deletion-detection-for-twitter-streaming-api-v2

doesn't seem to be enabled on v2